# how can display caption from another table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have two table

table A

```
add1 |add2 | add3 

1    |2    |3
```

another table B contains what the add1,add2,add3 means

table B

```
add1           | add2       | add3       |
Caption1       | Caption2   | Caption3
```

I want to display like

```
Caption  | Value
Caption1 | 1
Caption2 | 2
Caption3 | 3
```

or

```
Caption1 | Caption2 | Caption3

1        | 2        | 3
```

how can do this in mysql ?
If it is not possible pls suggest a better structure for this need. Every month the caption may be changed.

Comment: caption1, caption2, caption3 are they column names??

Comment: no they are caption for add1,add2,add3 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE B (
  add varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  caption varchar(50)
);
CREATE TABLE A (
  add varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  value int
);
```

Then use this query:

```
SELECT caption, value
FROM A INNER JOIN B
ON A.add = B.add
```

But if you want to keep your table structure, you can do:

```
SELECT B.add1 Caption, A.add1 Value
FROM A, B
UNION ALL
SELECT B.add2, A.add2
FROM A, B
UNION ALL
SELECT B.add3, A.add3
FROM A, B
```